# Shapley Values using python

Tags: python

I have run a risk model and obtained the risk contribution of each participant in the model. I would like to know how I can calculate the Shapley value to get the marginal contribution of each member. the data looks as follows;

```
Firm         Expected losses
A            6,103.40 
B            12,370.25 
C            11,897.43 
D            5,199.82 
E            26,384.77 
F            5,747.24 
G            31,206.84 
H            23,272.48 
H            4,483.49 
I            11,357.89 
Total Risk   138,023.60
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research on this at all?  There is at least one package dedicated to Shapley values:  https://github.com/slundberg/shap

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is. But I made an implementation of the calculation of shapley values from scratch. It uses Monte-Carlo sampling and works quite well, and helped me to understand the procedure better.

You can find it here: https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/shapley-values-from-scratch/